# Careers: How Much Attention to Expect?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

I'm a big fan of SO and the Careers site idea is great.

I have had a profile with Careers for some time, although my profile was only public during the times I was looking for new opportunities (most recently for the last two weeks).

The job market is very hot right now, and I have very marketable skills (mainly MS technologies).  I have my resume posted on other sites and get a pretty massive amount of calls/emails on a daily basis.  However, I am much more interested in the kinds of companies that would post jobs or search for resumes on a site like this (Joel's Software test, etc.).

I have simply not gotten much response from having my profile public on Careers.  This time around (again, the last two weeks) I have yet to be contacted by a company.  When I had my profile marked public the last time around, I got contacted twice (and neither a very good match). (Edit: after checking the stats as requested, it was actually 5 times).

I'm not complaining, as this is a free service and (again) I really like the concept.  What I'm wondering is if there is something flawed in my profile, if MS technologists are not in particular demand by companies that use Careers (maybe Open Source is more what they are looking for), or if this simply isn't the type of job board that produces a lot of response volume.  Maybe fewer responses but higher signal-to-noise ratio?

Edit: maybe a more direct question: do others who use Careers tend to get a fair number of responses, or just occasional responses?

Comment: If you want feedback on your profile, can you link to it?

Comment: Happy to receive feedback, although that wasn't my main reason for asking: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/psandler.

Comment: Not knowing the technologies you work in, it looks pretty good to me as far as I can tell... Maybe add some more tags to your "likes" list in case search is influenced by that? But then, it's supposed to be the likes list and not the "can do" list. I don't know, the careers team should be able to say whether it'll matter. One thing we can't see from the outside, though: are you sure you have the "looking for..." setting set to the correct geographic location(s)? And what does the careers front page say how many views your profile has? If it's very many, then maybe something needs reworking.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Here are the stats:  Public views:15
Employer views:23
Search hits:138
Email inquiries from employers:5
Email responses to employers:2  (both of the last two stats are from previous times it was public)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe there's indeed an issue with your searchability - for comparison, I have 2120 search hits, and 80 employer views (I would need a work visa so employers will pass me by in the results). But then, I have stated the entire US in my location. What location are you targeting? If it's a city, you might want to try widening it to county or state level (whichever the system accepts, I'm not sure)

Comment: Tagging this "support" - maybe someone from the careers team can chime in

Answer (score 5):

Here are some thoughts and intuitions...

Your profile suggest you are seeking a senior position, perhaps even an architect positon with a company on the MS stack. And in a very specific locale: Chicago. As of today, there are 17 postings in the Chicago area with C# listed; 4 of which have some type of lead/senior position. That's not very many openings.

Even though the company may have posted on Careers, they may not be searching the Career profiles. Rather, I suspect that there are several candidates on Careers contacting the posting company directly. Perhaps the posting companies are already receiving an overload of candidates contacting them directly?

In my experience (U.S. based), many companies who are at the size of needing the type of position you are seeking will use recruiters. And these recruiters typically have a pool of already known candidates. And the recruiters may not know about the open position until after the job has been posted on Careers.

From this [Success Story](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35080/144980), the recruiter contacted the candidate a week after the original posting company contacted the candidate. This would tie back to my theory above that the company has already been contacted by several candidates before they actively searched Careers. (I realize there is an obvious hole in this theory, but that's whay it's a theory).

Maybe a different approach would be in order, i.e., Contact the posting companies and not wait for them to contact you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am indeed contacting companies from their job listings, and do work with recruiters.  I think you're probably right in that the type of position I am looking for is probably not as common as more junior level positions.